# c++: Storing ostream in a List

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a function

```
foo(ostream& os)
```

which writes to the `ostream` passed to it.

I now want to write a test and therefore would like to store whatever is written by `foo` into a list.

What is a clean way of doing this?

Comment: Well the way I did it was to pass an ofstream to the function, write the output to a file, and then read from the file into a list; but that is of course ugly...

Comment: @user695652 Which kind of _list_? `std::list<>` actually?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ yes a std::list

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that writing tests shouldn't involve modifying the internals of your code. What you should be testing is the state of your `ostream` object before and after passing it to `foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate the list with a `std::ostringstream` instance:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

void foo(std::ostream& out) { out << "test1"; } // example implementation

void test_foo()
{
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    foo(buffer);
    assert(buffer.str() == "test1");
}
```